# Excel 2016: Sum values, excluding duplicate values and hidden cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

For example, if I have the following data in `A1:A6`:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

The total sum would be: **12**

If I exclude duplicate values, the sum would be: **6**

But if the first two rows are hidden because of data filtering, I need to exclude them from the sum as well, which would change the sum to: **5**

Answer (score 0):

How does this work (thanks to [this page](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/504802-sum-row-while-ignoring-duplicates-another-row.html)), entered as an array (with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(IF(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(A$1,ROW(A$1:A$6)-ROW(A$1),0,1)),IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$1:A$6<>"",MATCH("~"&A$1:A$6,A$1:A$6&"",0)),ROW(A$1:A$6)-ROW(A$1)+1),A$1:A$6))),$A$1:$A$6))
```